# Filesystem compatible with ONLY MacOS and Linux

Tags: filesystems

I'm looking for a filesystem that supports reading and writing operations on both MacOS and Linux, but preferably not Windows.
Is there such a thing, and if so, how well is it supported?

Comment: ZFS? On Mac: https://openzfsonosx.org.

Comment: Care to describe the use case?  It's a rather odd question without some context.

Comment: @Tim perhaps he's multibooting and doesn't want Windows users to access the data. This could be a case of security through obscurity or maybe he just wants an extra safety against unintended usage which is totally OK.

Comment: You need a Venn diagram of file systems - perhaps a nice project for someone who's interested (you?) :)  AFAIK, such a file system does not exist. And Apple is driving toward "closed" as fast as they can. [For example, this doc was last updated 7 yrs ago](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/FileSystem/Articles/MacOSXAndFiles.html), and comes with warnings that it's no longer valid. There's an [`ext2 in user space` project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fuse/) (last update in 2014), but getting it to run on a current version??